# CKEditor toolbar hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, textarea, toolbar

I don't want to show the toolbar of CKEditor.

[image]

I tried:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id='a' name='a' ></textarea><br>
```

**Javascript**

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'a', {
    toolbarCanCollapse : true,                  

              allowedContent: true
} );
```

But then also it is showing the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toolbarCanCollapse` will not work in `CKEDITOR.inline`, use `CKEDITOR.replace`.

Also, `toolbarCanCollapse` will not hide the toolbar automatically, it is just a button at the bottom-right corner in the toolbar, which helps to toggle the toolbar (Hide/Show), by default toolbar is shown and `toolbarCanCollapse` is disabled.

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('a', {
  toolbarCanCollapse: true, //Button to toggle toolbar (show/hide) 
  toolbarStartupExpanded: false, //This will hide toolbar by default.
  height: "60px" //I just gave the height if you want textarea to be small, just like it is in CKEDITOR.inline.
});
```